# Limit of function in $H^1(\mathbb{R}_+;\mathbb{C})$

Tags: calculus, sobolev-spaces, holder-spaces

Let $H^1(\mathbb{R}_+;\mathbb{C})$ the space of function in $L^2(\mathbb{R}_+;\mathbb{C})$ with weak derivative in the same space. Show that
\begin{equation}
lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 0
\end{equation}

Comment: What is $f$ ? what do you mean by Holder function ? Your question has no sense.

Comment: $f \in H^1(\mathbb{R}_+;\mathbb{C})$ thought it was obvious

Comment: @Surb removed my suppositions just want to know if a function in $H^1$ goes to zero at $+\infty$

Comment: In general, it holds that $H^1(\mathbb{R}^n) = H^1_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$. You can try to prove that by approximation (using mollifiers).

Comment: Also, I think that you need Meyers-Serrin theorem to prove it.